# Application of Resultant in Computer Algebra

Tags: polynomials, computer-science, computer-algebra, applications, resultants

Can you guys give me some application of resultant in Computer Algebra, it will be amazing if you guys can give me some paper or book to read more. Thanks so much

Comment: Why do you expect such applications, and why are they particularly interesting?  Without some context, this seems too broad to be an appropriate question for MO.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not the best forum to ask such a question; nevertheless I can provide some answer. You may like the paper [Computing resultant matrices with Macaulay2 and Maple](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00069898/document) by Busé, which not only provides actual implementations of resultants in computer algebra, but also examples and applications. In addition, the book [Modern computer algebra (3rd edition)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modern-computer-algebra/DB3563D4013401734851CF683D2F03F0) by von zur Gathen and Gerhard includes a chapter on resultants and how they can be used to control the coefficients in the computation of the gcd of two polynomials.